# How can I get the LOADED content of iframe with Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to get info from a website but it uses an iframe that won't work on an external site/page. The iframe only works on that page and is obfuscated. The loaded iframe content can be seen with inspect element but can not be seen in source code. I tried seeing innerHTML of the iframe with developer console but it shows obfuscated code.

I want to see what the Javascript code sends as result to browser on THAT page.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I simply used Chromium with those arguments. Apparently you need to disable web security to get data from iframe that points another domain.

chromium --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials --user-data-dir=/tmp

After this, in Javascript to get the contents:

document.getElementById("myFrame").contentWindow.document.body